# Is it possible to create several subwindows in the main window area in JavaFX2?

Tags: javafx-2

I think the following screenshot from mIRC will help you to understand my problem.

[image: multiple subwindows in mIRC]

I have a main Stage (1), and in some Pane (or any other container) (2), I would like to add several subwindows (3) in such way so **they cannot be moved outside the owning window** and they **are not visible/selectable in the OS taskbar**.

Is there a way to do it in JavaFX 2.2?
If not with windows (separate Stages), is it doable with any other movable containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no framework in JavaFX 2.2 to facilitate this.

You can track and vote for a JavaFX [Docking Framework](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14039) feature request using the JavaFX issue tracker.

You can create such a framework yourself using the public JavaFX API.  Using Stages, it might be a little difficult to get exactly the behaviour you want, but I think it would be possible if you used custom moveable Panes which are placed inside your main application stage.

However, until an official implementation of a docking framework is provided, you may be better off using an existing application framework like NetBeans and embedding your JavaFX components inside [JFXPanels within frames created by the existing framework](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/a_docking_framework_module_system).

To answer some of your specific questions.

> are not visible/selectable in the OS taskbar.

Before you show your new subwindow, invoke subwindow.[initOwner](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner%28javafx.stage.Window%29) to set the owner of the subwindow to the primary stage of your application.

> they cannot be moved outside the owning window

You could add listeners to the x, y, width and height properties of the subwindows and the primary window.  In the listener code reposition the subwindows if an attempt is made to move them outside of the bounds of the parent window.   This strategy could prove a bit clunky if size and location change notifications are processed by the operating system before your JavaFX listeners receive the notifications (which I think is likely to be the case).

Comment: Thanks, though it's kinda disappointing how limited JavaFX seems to be at the moment

Answer (score 1):

See [VFXWindows](http://mihosoft.eu/?p=365) project. It allows you to create windows and sub-windows within JavaFX app. It is available as part of [JFXtras 2](http://jfxtras.org/) package.